"Undefined" error with tcolorbox despite being installed
Issue
Today I switched over to compiling LaTeX locally as opposed to Overleaf, and I am having issues with running the following code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]     
    My box. 
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{document}

I receive the following errors within VS Code's "Problems" window:
Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing code ...UseTaggingSocket

Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing code ...}\SuspendTagging

Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing end aux  ...esumeTagging

Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing end aux  ...aggingSocket

Along with several warnings of the form: Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!.
Edit: Here is my .log file: https://blueflame202.github.io/quantum_notes.log
which is the .log file corresponding to the code above.
What I've Tried
I have tried verifying that I have the necessary packages involved by looking at tlmgr info tcolorbox, it looks like this:
installed:   Yes
revision:    71769
sizes:       run: 601k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 6.2.0
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  boxing colour verbatim listing macro-demo
cat-contact-bugs: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues
collection:  collection-latexextra

which seems normal to me. I wanted to be fancy so I tried to do a BasicTex installation from https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html, so that I could just have the bare minimum setup and install things as I needed them. On top of the basic installation, I have installed several packages through tlmgr.
I also looked around for similar issues by other people, but I didn't find anything that really helped me isolate or determine the issue further.
I also tried compiling with both pdflatex and with Latexmk (although I think the latter might just call pdflatex under the hood) but the issue persists with both.
Any feedback and help would be extremely appreciated! Thank you!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document -- MWE (Minimal Working Example) -- which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is.

Those are errors from the pdfmanagement test phase. Are you using an unsupported package? If not, are you sure everything you have installed is in sync? Have you tried disabling pdf management at least temporarily for testing?

Sanity check: is this the first error in your log file? Note that you can't tell anything about the packages you need from the output you show, but a missing package would produce an error to that effect.

If I insert your code fragment to simple small document like: \documentclass{article} \usepackage{tcolorbox} \begin{document} \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]     My box. \end{tcolorbox} \end{document} I get expected result. Compilation doesn't produce any errors, any warning and any bad box. This means that showed code fragment is not source of your problem, but it is in part of your code which you not show to us. Therefore, a MWE which cause your troubles is essential us.

you are using a new tcolorbox with an old LaTeX format. Update your system.

@Zarko Updated to complete a small document! I get what you mean though, the fragment isn't actually that helpful in understanding the issue, partly because I don't know what the issue stems from myself. It seems to work in Overleaf but not locally. The snippet you mentioned gives the expected result doesn't work on my system.

@cfr Hmm, I'm pretty new to reading the log files so I might be missing something, but the first error I see is: "/Users/aathreyakadambi/Documents/school/berkeley/physics 137a/notes/quantum_notes.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing code ...UseTaggingSocket
{tcb/drawing/begin}\Suspen...
l.8 \end{tcolorbox}" underneath some stuff about package "epstopdf-base". It then says: "The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed."

your example just produces ! LaTeX Error: File \NotesTemplate.sty' not found.`   please provide an example that does not use local files, or show that file in yoru question, after removing any lones you can remove while still showing the error

@DavidCarlisle Oh right, sorry that .sty is just a file I used, but it doesn't work even if I just do \usepackage{tcolorbox}. Edited the question.

your new example works without error with a current latex.  Show your log file from this example in a code block so lines are preserved it's impossible to read error messages in comments as line endings are required to understand the message, but Ulrike is probably right and you have an old latex and a new tcolorbox,

@UlrikeFischer I think that sounds right because I was noticing that array.sty and the tabular environment weren't working for me. But I tried sudo tlmgr update --all --self and that didn't find any updates or fix anything. Is there another way I should be updating my system?

doesn't mactex have its own mactex way of handling updates rather than using sudo tlmgr ?

@DavidCarlisle Maybe it does? I'm not actually sure because I got it yesterday, and I should mention that I got BasicTex, but I think it should be very similar? But that's also why I'm a bit surprised that it would be an old version because I installed it yesterday.

I edited my question to add the .log file in case that would help!

but anyway I now noticed your log link and Ulrike is right you have a new July 2024 tcolorbox but a 2023 latex that will not work, either you are missing an update or you have an old 2023 pdflatex.fmt in your local path

what does kpsewhich -engine=pdftex  --all pdflatex.fmt report

@DavidCarlisle It just points to the location of my pdflatex.fmt, which seems to be: /Users/aathreyakadambi/Library/texlive/2024basic/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

bingo. That is your problem, delete that and run sudu fmtutil-sys --all

you have used sudo to install a system wide tex but at some point you have run fmtutil (not fmtutil-sys) and made yourself a personal pdflatex.fmt and you keep seeing that even if you update the system wide tex

@DavidCarlisle WOAH that worked!!! You're amazing, thank you so much!  In general, does that mean I have a local version that I could be getting rid of? I'm assuming all the local stuff is in /Users/aathreyakadambi/Library/texlive/ whereas the system stuff is in /usr/local/texlive? Are they redundant?

no you have the correct installed files from the basictex repo but you somehow opted to build a personal copy from those files which then hides the new format when you do an update.

oh ok, that's interesting. you're right, I think I did run sudo fmtutil at some point because I didn't realize there was a system-wide option. thank you so much! :-)

The log shows a 2023 latex format being used with a July 2024 tcolorbox . Beware making personal user formats (fmtutil) in a system wide tex system as the formats will work but they will not be over-written or updated when the system wide tex is later updated.
kpsewhich -engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt

will reveal all your pdflatex formats. If (as shown in comments under the question) you have formats in your local tree delete them and then re-run
fmtutil-sys to remake the formats in the system tree.
